# How to split text and string from excel into separate colums

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to separate text and string from a single cell into separate columns.
Please find below an entry:
70000049Isha

Comment: Could you give more examples?  There are many different methods that could be used depending on the inputs.

Comment: Since you don't seem to understand what you're being told (and what's being asked of you), your example, `70000049Isha` can be split into columns in thousands of ways, such as `7`+`0000049Isha`, `70`+`000049Isha`, `70000`+`049Is`+`ha`, etc.  If empty columns are allowed, the possibilities are infinite.  We don't know what you want. You won't get a better answer until you ask a better question.

Answer (score 2):

"text" in Excel is the same as "string".

You can use Data > Text to Columns to split up a column. If the data is set up with a delimiter, like a comma, semicolon or tab between fields, use the "delimited" option and specify the delimiter.

If the data is structured with the same character length for each column, use the "fixed width" option and set the break points in step 2 of the wizard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but all the row's have different string&text length

Comment: Right. Read my post again. String and Text are the same for Excel. How, then, would you describe the logic that determines where the split should be applied????????????? BTW, 1 row, 2 rows. No need for an apostrophe for a plural. Basic English grammar rules.